# Specify different email recipients for each Jenkins pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created multiple Jenkins pipeline projects, based on different Git branches, for the same code base. I am using the Email Extension plugin to notify users once a build has completed. The email recipients are configured using the Default Recipients setting in the Extended E-mail Notification section of the Jenkins System Configuration. That information is then used in the Jenkins Pipeline Post step to actually send the notification (using the DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS environment variable). I would like to override the DEFAULT_RECIPEINTS for each project without changing the Jenkins pipeline file. How do I do this?

The Email Extension plugin documentation calls out setting a Post Build action, but I don't see that in the project settings (because it is a pipeline project).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a [presendScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/#plugin-content-script-trigger-options) in the project or globally. The `presendScript` will be executed before sending an Email. In contrast, `postendScript` will be executed after sending the emails. Within the `presendScript` you will have access to `build` details and `project` details. So based on this information you can change the recipient list. Following is how you can set a new recipient in the `presendScript`.

```
import javax.mail.Message.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;

msg.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,  new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress('abc@abc.org'));
```

Comment: Where do I add the presendScript for a specific project? I don't want to change the Jenkins pipeline file.

Comment: @PT2550 You can't add them to a specific project without changing the Pipeline. What you can do is Globally add the script and conditionally execute it based on the Project name.

Comment: I have a default recipients list created in the global configuration (DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS). Could I override DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS using the Environment Injector plugin?

Comment: @PT2550 I don't think without altering the Pipeline you can do this.